# Why are my clan members ineligible for wars?

Tags: clash-of-clans

My clan can't do a war because people are ineligible. We don't know why they are.

I am a coleader and I'm trying to figure this out, we have 14 people in our clan and we do wars every day.

Why are our clan members ineligible?

Comment: By 'co-lander' you mean 'co-leader'?

Comment: ... And also, you do know that you only need 10 members to do a war and that any number (as long as it is a multiple of 5) can participate, while everybody else sit out; spectate?

Comment: I just added 1 person and it still sys not eligible and this person wasn't in A clan before

Comment: Regardless of how many players there are in your clan, you **must have at least 10 players who are eligible for war.**  Since your clan has 14 players, only **4 players** can be ineligible. Otherwise, all you can do is wait.

Comment: @aytimothy - I've never played CoC, so forgive me if this is a dumb question, but wait for *what* exactly? What makes a person eligible for wars? This seems to be what the OP wants to know

Comment: @Robotnik - When players are ineligible for war, they are on a timer, based on the remaining time of the war they left plus a bit. After that timer runs out, they can participate back into wars in their new clan. (This timer still runs even if they're *not* in a clan)

Comment: @aytimothy - Ah k. Can the timer be seen by players? Also: you should flesh that out into an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's a 10 on 10,your current members will be eligible for war,with 14 members total,only 10 out of 14 will be able to war.The rest will be in-eligible for war.If you have 15,then you can start war and all members are eligible for war as the war roster goes up by 5